# Angular 6 Array of http requests fails

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs, httpresponse

I need some help with this loop of http requests, Here i am trying to loop some requests and push response into an array but the code exists before i get any response. Thank you for your help and suggestions

```
 publicgetMultipleTeamsData(teamIds:Array<string>,dateRange:any):
    Observable<any[]>{
          let response = [];
          teamIds.forEach(teamId => {
            this.getTeamDetails(teamId, dateRange)
            .map( tdata => {
              response.push(tdata);
            });
          });
          return Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(response));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you planned to put some data to `response` in `map` and then `forkJoin` all responses but it doesn't work so :).
As for me, you should do in such way:

```
public getMultipleTeamsData(teamIds:Array<string>,dateRange:any): Observable<any[]>{
    let requests = [];
    teamIds.forEach(teamId => {
      requests.push(this.getTeamDetails(teamId, dateRange))
    });
    return Observable.forkJoin(...requests);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public getMultipleTeamsData(teamIds:Array<string>,dateRange:any) {
 let arrObservables = teamIds.map(teamId => this.getTeamDetails(teamId, dateRange))

 return Observable.forkJoin(...arrObservables);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
securityActions() {
  let response = [];
  teamIds.forEach(teamId => {
    this.getTeamDetails(teamId, dateRange)
      .map(tdata => {
        response.push(tdata);
      });
  });
  return Observable.forkJoin(Observable.of(response));
}
```

Let's talk it out :

> create an array of responses
>   for each team ID, make an HTTP and push the response in it once the call is done
>   Don't wait for the calls to end, and make HTTP calls out of the responses. 
>   Don't subscribe to the calls, which doesn't trigger them

If you want to make it work, try something like this :

```
return forkJoin(teamIds.map(ID => this.getTeamDetails(ID, dateRange)));
```